# BETWEEN Query Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which uses `BETWEEN` for showing the records between two dates. My query needs to show records whose `arrival_date` and `departure_date` between specific dates. But query somehow shows all records.

Column types are `DATE`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT art.* FROM accommodation_room_types art 
INNER JOIN accommodation_rooms ar ON art.id = ar.room_type
INNER JOIN accommodation a ON art.accommodation = a.id
WHERE a.id = 13 AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM booked_rooms br INNER JOIN booking b ON br.booking = b.id
    WHERE br.room = ar.id
    AND
    (
        b.arrival_date BETWEEN '2017-12-16' AND '2018-04-16'
    ) 
    OR
    (
        b.departure_date BETWEEN '2017-12-16' AND '2018-04-16'
    )
)
```

Even I write `BETWEEN 'asd' AND 'asd'`, it still shows all records and doesn't give any format error.
Is my query wrong for showing records between two specific dates?

Comment: What you need is more parenthesis `WHERE X AND ( (B) OR (C) )`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your logic is right or wrong, but your syntax is not doing what you intend.  I would suggest:

```
WHERE a.id = 13 AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM booked_rooms br INNER JOIN
                      booking b
                      ON br.booking = b.id 
                 WHERE br.room = ar.id AND
                       (b.arrival_date BETWEEN '2017-12-16' AND '2018-04-16' OR  
                        b.departure_date BETWEEN '2017-12-16' AND '2018-04-16'
                       )    
                )
```

It strikes me that all that empty space in the query makes it hard to see that your logic was written as:  `A AND B OR C`.  Your intention (presumably) is `A AND (B OR C)`.

Comment: I am getting an error with yours: Unknown column `ar.id` in `on clause`

Comment: @MalenaT . . . I misread that condition.  It is just a correlation condition. You just need parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute `1` for `*`

The way you wrote query, it always return 1, regardless of conditions. Moreover, that is totally legit.

Comment: The OP is returning `1` just to return some sort of data. Your fix is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: If a query is being used in `EXISTS`, it doesn't matter what columns it returns -- `EXISTS` just tests whether any rows matched the conditions.

Comment: you both right, I was wrong, my bad